# Pods not moved on host failure

Tags: kubernetes

i have setup myself a simple 1 master and 3 nodes setup running on Ubuntu based on the book "Kuberenetes Up & Running" in combination with the official documentation.

It basically works until i shutdown one of the `worker` nodes.
After a few seconds the nodes-running-state switches to `unknown`.
The pods keep report the state `running` even if the pods are located on the offline node.

Shouldn't k8s move these pods to a different healthy host? 
Am i missing something?

thanks in advice!

Comment: how long did you wait for the pods to move?

Comment: how long should i wait? Doesn't this happend "instantly" (im used to docker swarm)?

I waited a couple of minutes

Comment: https://github.com/mattmattox/drain-node-on-crash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Kubernetes version 1.13 and higher, pod eviction on node failures/not-ready conditions is actually controlled by **taints and tolerations**. `--pod-eviction-timeout` parameter is not used anymore.

When a node goes down or is not ready, node-controller/kubelet will add the following taints to the node - `node.kubernetes.io/unreachable` and `node.kubernetes.io/not-ready`. All pods tolerate these taints for 300 seconds by default. You can control this toleration time cluster wide for all pods with flags to `kube-api-server` and also per pod using `tolerations` object in pod spec.

**Cluster Wide configuration:**

You can modify the toleration time cluster wide using `--default-not-ready-toleration-seconds` and `--default-unreachable-toleration-seconds` flags to `kube-api-server`.

From [docs:](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/kube-apiserver/)

```
--default-not-ready-toleration-seconds int     Default: 300
Indicates the tolerationSeconds of the toleration for notReady:NoExecute that is added by default to every pod that does not already have such a toleration.
--default-unreachable-toleration-seconds int     Default: 300
```

**Per pod configuration:**

You can also modify the toleration time per pod using the following configuration.

```
tolerations:
  - key: "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable"
    operator: "Exists"
    effect: "NoExecute"
    tolerationSeconds: 120
  - key: "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready"
    operator: "Exists"
    effect: "NoExecute"
    tolerationSeconds: 120
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/#taint-based-evictions

Answer (score 2):

By default pods won't be moved for 5m minutes which is configurable via the following flag on the controller manager `--pod-eviction-timeout duration`.

After 5 min if it still not happening(stateful sets) you need to delete the node using `kubectl delete node`  which would trigger a reschedule of the pods on the node.

From Kubernetes version 1.13 and higher, pod eviction on node failures/not-ready conditions is controlled by taints and tolerations. --pod-eviction-timeout parameter is ignored.

Cluster wide configuration can be configured via kubelet parameter.

```
--default-not-ready-toleration-seconds int     Default: 300Indicates the tolerationSeconds of the toleration for notReady:NoExecute that is added by default to every pod that does not already have such a me toleration.

--default-unreachable-toleration-seconds int     Default: 300Indicates the tolerationSeconds of the toleration for unreachable:NoExecute that is added by default to every pod that does not already have such a toleration.
```

If you want to manage this attribute in POD level, you can add tolerations.

```
spec:
  tolerations:
  - key: "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable"
    operator: "Exists"
    effect: "NoExecute"
    tolerationSeconds: 30
  - key: "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready"
    operator: "Exists"
    effect: "NoExecute"
    tolerationSeconds: 30
```

Checkout this related [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/55713)

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/#taint-based-evictions

Comment: Actually - I guess I was too impatient.
Thanks @arghya-sadhu

Answer (score 1):

I was able to work around this using this [script](https://github.com/mattmattox/drain-node-on-crash) to force drain any node that has gone into Not Ready status for greater than 5 mins (adjustable) then it will un cordon node the after it returns.